# How to dynamically load an asset (pdf) in an angular app using webpack?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, pdf, webpack

I am trying to load a pdf into my angular app running on `webpack dev server` using HTML `<object>` tag with `data` attribute.

Since the pdf path is generated at run time and is `absolute` like `C:\test.pdf`.

It is not loaded into the UI but rather `console` logs the error -

`Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/test.jpeg`

However the production build of the app which doesn't run on hosting server but as static html works fine. Also, relative path works fine as well.

How can i load the pdf ?

`webpack.common.js`

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const path = require('path');
const rootDir = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');

module.exports = {
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts'],
    modules: [rootDir, path.join(rootDir, "node_modules")]
},

module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'html-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[ext]'
        },
        {
           test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
           use: [
                { loader: "style-loader" },
                { loader: "css-loader" },
                { loader: "sass-loader",
                    options: {
                        includePaths: ["node_modules/"]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]},
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html'
        }),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
            path.resolve(__dirname, '../src')
        )
    ]
};
```

`webpack.dev.js`

```js
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');

const path = require('path');
const rootDir = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');

commonConfig.entry = {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/main.ts'
};

commonConfig.module.rules.unshift({
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader', 'angular-router-loader']
});

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {

  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

  output: {
      path: path.resolve(rootDir, 'dist'),
      publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
      filename: '[name].js',
          chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js'
      },

      plugins: [
          new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
      ],

      devServer: {
          historyApiFallback: true,
          stats: 'minimal'
      }
});
```

Comment: can you give a snippet of your webpack config file and please tell where pdf is being generated in asset folder.

Comment: @PraveshKhatri I have added the code snippet.

Comment: I think you need to add `.pdf` extension in file-loader in webpack.common.js as it will put your file to the assets folder.

you have another aprroach that you can copy your pdf's to your destination folder in assets by `copyWebpackPlugin`

Comment: @PraveshKhatri I have tried doing that, it doesn't work. Maybe because this asset is not known to webpack until runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could tell the devServer from where to serve files.

```
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true,
  stats: 'minimal',
  contentBase: ['./dist', 'C:\\']
}
```

Then you can load your file with `<... src="/file_name.ext" ... />`

But I would not recommend adding C:\ as contentBase. If you have the possiblity, define another output directory for your generated PDF.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But why won't you recommend using it?

Comment: Nice. Because it would allow you to include every file from your C drive.

Comment: Ok. But for current use case that is not going to be an issue. Appreciate it!